# How to overcome serialversion uid warnings in java?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, apt, java, applet

as i run this command : javac -Xlint  Helloworld.java
Helloworld.java:8: warning: [deprecation] Applet in java.applet has been deprecated
public class Helloworld extends Applet 
                                ^
Helloworld.java:8: warning: [serial] serializable class Helloworld has no definition of serialVersionUID
public class Helloworld extends Applet 
       ^
2 warnings

what shoud i do now?
i am unable to run applet viewer code

Comment: It is hard to see how this relates directly to the Ubuntu operating system, which is the topic of this forum. You might have better luck asking somewhere like Stack Overflow, but when you do, please provide much more information about your setup, OS, software, what you were doing when the error ocurred, etc. Without more information it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Applets are a dead technology. They are not supported by recent versions of Java or any current browser.